# Youtube upload API and cordova / phonegap

Tags: cordova, meteor, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am writing a cordova app that lets the user record a video and upload it to youtube via their api.

If I use a file input and access the file via

`$('#file').get(0).files[0]`

I receive a `file` object which is able to uploaded without a problem.

If I record a video I receive a medialist object.
I can then call `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL( video[0].localURL , success, fail);`

On the success callback I receive a filelist object. Which also will not be accepted.

On this `filelist`object I can call `data.file(success,fail)` which finally returns me a file object. But when trying to upload to youtube I am getting a 308 error.

I suspect it has to do with permissions of accessing the local file path. If anyone has experience with this I would love to hear a way around it.

Here is the upload code:

```
UploadVideo.prototype.ready = function(accessToken, video) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
    this.gapi = gapi;
    this.authenticated = true;
    $this = this;

function result(data){
    function success(data){

        data.name = "VID_20150329_160037.mp4";
        console.log(data)
        $this.uploadFile( data );
    }
    data.file(success)

}
function fail(data){
    console.log(data)
}
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL( video[0].localURL , result, fail);


//this.uploadFile( $('#file').get(0).files[0] );

// $('#button').on("click", this.handleUploadClicked.bind(this));
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302 A 302 error is a redirect. This sounds like its either pointing to a deprecated endpoint, or the auth is not valid and rerouting away from the endpoint.

Comment: But it is working with this file object - $('#file').get(0).files[0]. So it has to be something about the file encoding

Comment: Hi, it's bee a while for this , but I'm currently working on a small app also trying to do a Youtube upload after a video is recorded, though I'm doing in angular/ionic. Is there a chance do you have a repo for this to see it as example?

Comment: How does one even acquire an access token?  gapi.client.init never returns when loaded in Cordova due to google's policy of disallowing loading outside HTTP/HTTPS
See:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js#supported-environments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this blogpost I managed to get metadata and file upload working:
http://lithostech.com/2013/10/upload-google-youtube-api-v3-cors/

By logging out the FileTransfer header information before it was sent, I could see the format was different:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="part"
{"snippet":{"title":"Video title","description":"Video description","tags":"Video tags","categoryId":22},"status":{"privacyStatus":"unlisted"}}
```

Should be:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="file.json"
Content-Type: application/json
{"snippet":{"title":"Video title","description":"Video description","tags":"Video tags","categoryId":22},"status":{"privacyStatus":"unlisted"}}
```

Here is an updated version including working metadata:

```
function uploadVideo(fileURL) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = 'file';
    options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = 'video/mpg';
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.headers = {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    };
    options.params = {
        "": {
            snippet: {
                title: 'Video title',
                description: 'Video description',
                tags: 'Video tags',
                categoryId: 22
            },
            status: {
                privacyStatus: 'unlisted'
            }
        }
    };
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileURL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,status', function (data) {
        console.log('upload success', data);
    }, function (e) {
        console.log('upload error', e);
    }, options, true);
    ft.onprogress = function (progressEvent) {
        console.log('onprogress: ' + ((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100) + '%');
    };
}
```

note that I modified my FileTransfer plugin slightly too:

FileTransfer.java
lines 374 - 376

```
beforeData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"").append(key.toString()).append("\";");
beforeData.append(" filename=\"").append("file.json").append('"').append(LINE_END);
beforeData.append("Content-Type: ").append("application/json").append(LINE_END).append(LINE_END);
```

After modifying a plugin in cordova/phonegap/ionic you will need to reload it. I do this by removing the platform and adding it again:

```
cordova platform remove android; cordova platform add android;
```

Comment: So does this only work on Android? or does IOS works out of the box.

Comment: I only tried this on Android, I presume you might need to modify the iOS FileTransfer plugin to support the Content Headers

Comment: Im getting an error though, unexpected part snippet & status. I've created a fork with the changes https://github.com/westonganger/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Comment: Are you able to log out the result it creates? I don't have an iOS device to hand! It could be that I leave the name blank: Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="file.json"

Comment: I was testing the android version using your code, not IOS.

Comment: Are you sending though params exactly as I showed above?, there is deliberately a blank object inside the params object

Comment: Would you please update the line numbers you are referring to in FileTransfer.java? I see two potential locations that you may be referring to now that the plugin itself has been updated: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/src/android/FileTransfer.java#L385

Comment: Never mind, I just got it to work! It goes into the for loop that builds the `beforeData`.

Comment: i used above code and i am able to upload video successfully but video name is saved as unknown how can i fix that issue @KimT

Comment: @manojrejinthala snippet: { title: 'Video title' should do it. Check if any of the title, description, tags, status are being updated. If not then probably the information is not POST'ing in the correct format. Did you modify FileTransfer plugin to support the format?

Comment: 3 years too late, but how do you handle authentication?

Comment: In my case was using Ionic + JavaScript so added a library called:
ngCordovaOauth and auth'd using the scopes:
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload' then added the access token received to the header: options.headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + $scope.youtubeAccount.access_token };

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it working. I needed to use the cordova filetransfer plugin

here is the code

```js
function postVideo(accessToken, fileURI) {
  var metadata = {
    snippet: {
      title: "test",
      description: "test",
      tags: ["youtube-cors-upload"],
      categoryId: 21
    },
    status: {
      privacyStatus: "unlisted"
    }
  }

  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.fileKey = "file";
  options.fileName = 'test';
  options.mimeType = "video/mp4";
  options.chunkedMode = false;

  options.headers = {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://meteor.local"
  };

  var params = new Object();
  params.part = Object.keys(metadata).join(',')

  options.params = params;
  console.log(options)
  var ft = new FileTransfer();
  ft.upload(fileURI, "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet", win, fail, options, true);

  ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
      // console.log(progressEvent)
      // loadingStatus.setPercentage(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
    } else {
      console.log('something not loading')
        // loadingStatus.increment();
    }
    console.log(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
  };
}

function win(r) {
  console.log(r)
  console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
  console.log("Response = " + r.response);
  console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
  console.log(error)
    // alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
  console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
  console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}
```

Comment: This is great, did you figure out how to pass through the correct metadata? when I use this example the title is unknown

Comment: Apologies I haven't tested the title as yet. Just had to put this project on the back burner. Best bet is to check if the data is being sent in the request. If not Google YouTube api help would be the best place to find out. Sorry I can't be of more help at the moment

Comment: Looks like the metadata can be passed through like this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#examples and this script https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/cors_upload.js

Comment: Check out my updated answer, youtube upload with metadata is working!!

Comment: how do you generate the access token from refresh token using java script ?
can you provide the code to do that too.

Comment: snippet and status are not binding i am getting title undefined

Comment: i am also getting title and other data undefined

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing information.

I had the same situation when I want to upload selected file in device by using the cordova plugin.

My case is not 308 error but it is the data of file which returned by cordova-file plugin have not right format  as Blob format of input file HTML.

So that, There is simple solution to fix issue. It is convert data of file to right Blob format of input file HTML.

I have used sample from Youtube Data API and reference links as below:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#examples
- https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/javascript

## The main idea of solution for fix this issue

*1) Convert data of file to Blob format of input file HTML.* 
*2) Modify content of upload_video.js file.*
*3) Modify content of cors_upload.js file.*

## The detail of solution

*1) Convert data of file to Blob format of input file HTML:*

○ Input content is file which returned by cordova-file plugin 
  ○ Use FileReader HTML5 to read file content as ArrayBuffer.
  ○ Use Blob object to create new content with data is converted.

*Convert data sample code

```
UploadVideo.prototype.convertToBlob = function (file, onSuccess) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = (function (event) {
            var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.result)], { type: file.type });
            onSuccess(blob);
          });
          reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        };
```

*2) Modify content of upload_video.js file:*

○ Create "myFile" property for  UploadVideo object which store selected file.
○ Retrieve data content which returned by cordova-file plugin and convert it to Blob format.

*Read file content and convert content to Blob sample code

```
 var self_ = this; //the instance of UploadVideo object
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileUri, function (fileEntry) {
              //success
              fileEntry.file(function(file){
                   //Store selected file to re-use when upload event
            self_.myFile = file;
            //We could use file as input of  convertToBlob ()
            self_.convertToBlob (file, function(blob){
                self_.myFile.newBlob  = blob;
            });
              });
          }, function (response) {
              //error
          });
```

○ Need to sure new Blob content is already for input of this.uploadFile()  in UploadVideo.prototype.handleUploadClicked() method.

*Modifiy source code in handleUploadClicked()

```
Replace:
   this.uploadFile($('#file').get(0).files[0]);
By new:
   this.uploadFile(this.myFile);
```

*3) Modify content of cors_upload.js file:*

○ Modify new upload content from MediaUploader.prototype.sendFile_() method

*Modify source code in sendFile_()

```
Replace:
   var content = this.file;
By new:
   var content = this.file.newBlob;
```

That is all my solution to fix this issue. With simple modification of source code.

Best Regards,
Dang Quynh.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing off of [Kim T's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31795940/763010), here's how to get it to work on iOS:

Modify the `CDVFileTransfer.m` file located in the `Plugins` directory of your xCode project with the code from this [pull request](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/pull/143/files). The modifications look like this:

**src/ios/CDVFileTransfer.m**

```
@@ -25,6 +25,7 @@ Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
+#import <Foundation/NSJSONSerialization.h>

@@ -203,6 +204,11 @@ - (NSURLRequest*)requestForUploadCommand:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command fileData
+        // if it is a valid json object get the NSString representation
 +        if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:val]){
 +            NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:val options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
 +            val = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 +        }
```

Then in that same file, within the `requestForUploadCommand` function as it iterates over the **key**s in `options`, change this line:

```
[postBodyBeforeFile appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

To this:

```
[postBodyBeforeFile appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"file.json\"\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

It probably doesn't matter, but I changed `options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` to `options:0` when using the code from the aforementioned pull request.

As soon as I made these changes, re-built the project in xCode and launched it on my wife's iPad, video upload to YouTube with meta tag information worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer is wrong and does not work. The correct answer is you should use the 2 part resumable upload method detailed in depth here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol

example:

```
  var videoResourceYT = //yt video resource goes here
  }

  videoResourceYT = JSON.stringify(videoResourceYT)
  var ftoptions = new FileUploadOptions();
  var ft = new FileTransfer();
  $.ajax({
    url:"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status",
    method:"POST",
    data: videoResourceYT,
    contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        beforeSend: function (request) {
              request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
              request.setRequestHeader("X-Upload-Content-Length", /*file length, not actually needed*/);
              request.setRequestHeader("X-Upload-Content-Type", "video/*");
        },
        success: function(ytuploadData, ytTextStatus, ytRequest){
          var nextUrlYT = ytRequest.getResponseHeader('Location');
          console.log(nextUrlYT)

          ftoptions.mimeType = "video/*";
          ftoptions.chunkedMode = false;
          ftoptions.headers = {
              "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token,
              "Content-Type": "video/*"
          };
          ftoptions.httpMethod = "PUT"


          //?part=snippet,status
          ft.upload(/*options go here*/);
        },
        error: function(e1,e2,e3){
        }
  })
```